# Is there a builtin method similar to Counter in Python?

Tags: raku

I've dug through the docs, but I can't seem to find anything similar to the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in Python.

I know I can write something similar trivially, but a builtin would be so convenient.

Trivial example:

`my %h; %h{$_}++ for @test;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Bag](https://docs.raku.org/type/Bag) class does what you want.

```
my %h is Bag = @test;
```

Or if you just want to coerce:

```
my $bag = @test.Bag;
```

In either case, you can use the object like any ordinary `Hash`.

```
# show sorted with most frequent first
say "{.key} seen {.value} times" for %h.sort: -*.value
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I knew there had to be a succinct way to do it.